# Ansible SSH passwd authentication successful, but publickey authentication fails

Tags: ssh, ansible, public-key, openssh

When using ansible, I authenticate using the following parameters:

```
-u bob -k -K -b
```

I get the output I want, but it turns out that Ansible fails publickey authentication on each system.

Selected output from /var/log/secure on one of the recipient systems:

```
Failed publickey for bob from $IP port $PORT ssh2

Accepted password for bob from $IP port $PORT ssh2
```

I'm making my through the documentation, but I have yet to find a method to prevent Ansible from attempting to use anything other than just passwd authentication.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Forget to mentioned that host_key_checking = False

Comment: Also that, SSH works fine when doing a SSH connection outside of using Ansible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add SSH client option `-o PreferredAuthentications=password` where applicable (Ansible inventory, extra-variables, ssh-config, etc.).

For example, for hosts file:

```
[myhosts]
host1 ansible_host=X.X.X.X ansible_ssh_extra_args="-o PreferredAuthentications=password"
```